# Notepad++ replace using variables

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++ I need to find every instance of the following:

```
<ApplicationPath>F:\software\VARIABLEA.zip</ApplicationPath>
```

with the following:

```
<ApplicationPath>F:\Games\VARIABLEA\VARIABLEA.m3u</ApplicationPath>
```

Where the filename in the first example, VARIABLEA, is to be used to modify the application path by inserting the VARIABLEA text where indicated.

Unfortunately, I can't wrap my head around how to accomplish this. Your pointers are appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Your description is a bit sparse.

Comment: @johnmoarr please see the modified question. I need to go from the first example to the second where the filename is used as a variable to modify the application path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a regular expression search and replace.

Search this: `<ApplicationPath>F:\\software\\([^.]*)\.zip<\/ApplicationPath>`

and replace with: `<ApplicationPath>F:\\Games\\$1\\$1.m3u</ApplicationPath>`.

If you want to understand how this expression is built, I suggest you copy and paste it on [here](https://regex101.com/r/jX4lQ4/2), since it explains it better than I can. But, basically, whatever your filename is, it captures it and uses it in the resulting path where the `$1` are.